# ADW - Query performance issues

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have an Azure SQL Warehouse setup of DW500c of gen2 and i have a Data Vault model in it with several tables.
I am trying to execute one query that i think is taking too much time.

Here is the query i have been executing:

```
SELECT 
    H_PROFITCENTER.[BK_PROFITCENTER]
    ,H_ACCOUNT.[BK_ACCOUNT]
    ,H_LOCALCURRENCY.[BK_CURRENCY]
    ,H_DOCUMENTCURRENCY.[BK_CURRENCY]
    ,H_COSTCENTER.[BK_COSTCENTER]
    ,H_COMPANY.[BK_COMPANY]
    ,H_CURRENCY.[BK_CURRENCY]
    ,H_INTERNALORDER.[BK_INTERNALORDER]
    ,H_VERSION.[BK_VERSION]
    ,H_COSTELEMENT.[BK_COSTELEMENT]
    ,H_CALENDARDATE.[BK_DATE]
    ,H_VALUETYPEREPORT.[BK_VALUETYPEREPORT]
    ,H_FISCALPERIOD.[BK_FISCALPERIOD]
    ,H_COUNTRY.[BK_COUNTRY]
    ,H_FUNCTIONALAREA.[BK_FUNCTIONALAREA]
    ,SLADI.[LINE_ITEM]
    ,SLADI.[AMOUNT]
    ,SLADI.[CREDIT]
    ,SLADI.[DEBIT]
    ,SLADI.[QUANTITY]
    ,SLADI.[BALANCE]
    ,SLADI.[LOADING_DATE]
FROM [dwh].[L_ACCOUNTINGDOCUMENTITEMS] AS LADI
    INNER JOIN [dwh].[SL_ACCOUNTINGDOCUMENTITEMS] AS SLADI ON LADI.[HK_ACCOUNTINGDOCUMENTITEMS] = SLADI.[HK_ACCOUNTINGDOCUMENTITEMS]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_PROFITCENTERAS H_PROFITCENTER ON H_PROFITCENTER.[HK_PROFITCENTER] =  LADI.[HK_PROFITCENTER]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_ACCOUNT AS H_ACCOUNT ON H_ACCOUNT.[HK_ACCOUNT] =  LADI.[HK_ACCOUNT]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_CURRENCY AS H_LOCALCURRENCY ON H_LOCALCURRENCY.[HK_CURRENCY] =  LADI.[HK_LOCALCURRENCY]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_CURRENCY   AS H_DOCUMENTCURRENCY  ON H_DOCUMENTCURRENCY.[HK_CURRENCY] =  LADI.[HK_DOCUMENTCURRENCY]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_COSTCENTER AS H_COSTCENTER  ON H_COSTCENTER.[HK_COSTCENTER] =  LADI.[HK_COSTCENTER]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_COMPANY AS H_COMPANY ON H_COMPANY.[HK_COMPANY] =  LADI.[HK_COMPANY]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_CURRENCY AS H_CURRENCY  ON H_CURRENCY.[HK_CURRENCY] =  LADI.[HK_CURRENCY]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_INTERNALORDERAS H_INTERNALORDER ON H_INTERNALORDER.[HK_INTERNALORDER] =  LADI.[HK_INTERNALORDER]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_VERSION AS H_VERSION ON H_VERSION.[HK_VERSION] =  LADI.[HK_VERSION]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_COSTELEMENT AS H_COSTELEMENT  ON H_COSTELEMENT.[HK_COSTELEMENT] =  LADI.[HK_COSTELEMENT]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_DATE AS H_CALENDARDATE ON H_CALENDARDATE.[HK_DATE] =  LADI.[HK_CALENDARDATE]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_VALUETYPEREPORTAS H_VALUETYPEREPORT ON H_VALUETYPEREPORT.[HK_VALUETYPEREPORT] =  LADI.[HK_VALUETYPEREPORT]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_FISCALPERIODAS H_FISCALPERIOD ON H_FISCALPERIOD.[HK_FISCALPERIOD] =  LADI.[HK_FISCALPERIOD]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_COUNTRY AS H_COUNTRY ON H_COUNTRY.[HK_COUNTRY] =  LADI.[HK_COUNTRY]
    LEFT JOIN dwh.H_FUNCTIONALAREAAS H_FUNCTIONALAREA ON H_FUNCTIONALAREA.[HK_FUNCTIONALAREA] =  LADI.[HK_FUNCTIONALAREA]
```

This query is taking me 22 minutes to execute.

I must say that it returns around 1200000000 rows.

`[L_ACCOUNTINGDOCUMENTITEMS]` and `[SL_ACCOUNTINGDOCUMENTITEMS]` are hash distributed by `[HK_ACCOUNTINGDOCUMENTITEMS]` column and all other tables were created with replicated table distribution.

Also, i activated in azure datawarehouse automatic statistics creation.

Can anyone help me to understand how can i speed it up?

Comment: Some diagnostic information, please ... Which tables are CCI or Heap? Under which Resource Class do your queries run, especially the ELT queries that build the tables? Are the hash-dist tables evenly distributed (not skewed)? Have Statistics been created (and updated) on all tables?

Comment: And, if possible, please post a link to a query plan generated by putting the word EXPLAIN in front of your query. It is an XML file that tells us exactly what is going on under the covers.

Comment: What are you doing with the 1.2 billion rows? Are you returning it over the network? Or are you doing a CTAS to create a new table?

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: Hi everyone. To give some answers, i must say that all tables were created using Clustered ColumnStore Index. I was returning all rows over the network but i tried to create a table with all rows returned from the query using CTAS, but it take the same time.

Comment: Here is the query plan for the query: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mIOcEp37n7yRKvkwSZOXybAW6MSq_1qN/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things to try out to see if you make this faster -

Create a table using 'Create Table as Select' (CTAS) with RoundRobin option for your query and take the timing of that. I have a feeling that returning that large amount of rows to your client could be a big contributor to the time. If the CTAS finishes in lets say 5 minutes, you can safely say that the rest of the time is being taken by return operation.

If not, You can materialize some of the left joins into a table and then add that table to the main query to see if that finishes faster.

You can also look at explain plans to see if you can cut down some steps by aligning the tables on a common key.

Comment: Hi Murshed. Thank you for your help. I tried to create a table with all returned rows from this query using CTAS, but it took the same time. How can i share the query plan xml file from the query here?

Comment: Here is the query plan for this query: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mIOcEp37n7yRKvkwSZOXybAW6MSq_1qN/view?usp=sharing